# How to prevent updating an array in nested object from turning it into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a state which is a nested object that contains arrays at some levels, and I want to update a value, something like this:

`a.b.c[0].d = "new value"`

When trying to do a deep copy during a Redux update, it converts my array `c` into an object, and so my app breaks as my array operations no longer exist on the copied object.

```
a: {
    ...state.a,
    b:{
        ...state.a.b,
        c: {
            ...state.a.b.c,    // This converts c from array to object
            [0]:{
                ...state.a.b.c[0],
                d: "new value"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

How do I deep copy `c` without converting it to an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `c` changes to an `Object` because you wrote so)

```
a: {
    ...state.a,
    b:{
        ...state.a.b,
        c: [
            {
                ...state.a.b.c[0],
                d: "new value"
            },
            ...state.a.b.c.slice(1)
        ]
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work, but how do I specify the right index to update if is not 0, eg., c[5]

Comment: For instance `c: [...state.a.b.c.slice(0, 4), {...state.a.b.c[4], d: 'new value'}, ...state.a.b.c.slice(0, 5)]`